# How to get parameters from url in Eclipse Rap 2.0?

Tags: eclipse

How can i get the parameters given by the URL in Eclipse RAP 2.0?

Example URL: http://www.example.com:8080/rap?startup=foo&var1=value1&var2=value2

In RAP 1.5 this worked:

```
HttpServletRequest request = RWT.getRequest();
String var1 = request.getParameter( "var1" );
String var2 = request.getParameter( "var2" );
```

How can i get the request parameters in RAP 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RWT.getRequest().getParameterMap().size()
```

I tried it before i posted my question, but it did not work.
I found this bug today:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404546

So it seems like i just have to wait for RAP 2.1 M2 :)